# Parametrization for implicit function

Tags: parametric, maple

> $3y^2=x(1-x)^2$

By differentiation we can knwo that the sketch of this graph has one circle.

I want to draw a graph in maple. Implicit plot does not work well

So I will use parametric way.

Please give me a parametrization.

Comment: Why not just solve for $y$ and plot the resulting two curves?

Comment: Thank you. I tried, and work well.

Comment: @aschepler seems like your comment is an answer now, maybe it's worth putting it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial equations in two variables can be plotted like this

```
algcurves[plot_real_curve](3*y^2 - x*(1-x)^2, x, y);
```

[image: Maple plot]

You can improve the plots returned by **implicitplot** by including the **gridrefine** option:

```
plots:-implicitplot(3*y^2 = x*(1-x)^2, x= 0..2, y= -1..1, gridrefine= 3);
```

A parameterization of a polynomial curve can be obtained by

```
algcurves[parameterization](3*y^2 - x*(1-x)^2, x, y, t);
```

Maple responds:

```
[3*t^2/(t^2-2*t+1), -t*(-1+2*t+2*t^2)/(-3*t^2+3*t+t^3-1)]
```